# Leading and trailing margins around a UIView in UIToolbar

Tags: ios, uitoolbar, margins

Is it possible to layout a `UIView` in `UIToolbar` such that -

1. I can give leading and trailing margin (20% either side), or
2. If possible, make that view "**follow readable width**" within toolbar?

E.g. In this spec, the `UIProgressView` inside bottom `UIToolbar` of navigation controller aligns itself with `readableContentGuide` of `UITableViewCell` in `UITableView` as per designer.

[image]

Tough one I guess but any thoughts or code snippet?

**EDIT**: Below is the code snippet to add progress view in toolbar. This stretches the progress view close to left and right margins (edge) of tool bar (by default). However I don't know how I can configure margins as per above requirements (#1 or #2), otherwise it works great for all devices/sizes etc.

```
func setupProgressView() {
    progressView = UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: .bar)
    guard let toolbar = navigationController?.toolbar else {
        return
    }
    toolbar.addSubview(progressView!)
    progressView!.tintColor = .blue
    progressView!.trackTintColor = .lightGray
}
```